# Angular Dropdown Doesn't Work, Looks Like a List

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my code, I defined a mat-chip-list so that a user can select multiple items from a list of elements. The code doesn't have any errors, but the `mat-chip-list` doesn't appear as a dropdown. I should be able to select elements from it, but I can't do that either. It just looks like a list as it shown below. What should I do to fix this?

HTML:

```
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100-p" fxFlex>
                <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
                <mat-chip-list #chipList>
                    <mat-chip *ngFor="let prm of receiptList"
                              [selectable]="selectable"
                              [removable]="removable"
                              (removed)="removeReceipt(prm)">
                              {{prm.StockIntegrationCode +' - '+ prm.StockShortName}}
                        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                    </mat-chip>
                    <input #receiptInput
                           [formControl]="receiptCtrl"
                           [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addReceipt($event)">
                </mat-chip-list>
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="receiptSelected($event)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let receipt of filteredReceipts| async" [value]="receipt">
                        {{receipt.StockIntegrationCode +' - '+ receipt.StockShortName}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

TS:

```
  receiptList: IReceipt[] = [];
  receipt: IReceipt[];

  allReceipts: IReceipt[] = [];


  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;

  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];


  receiptCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredReceipts: Observable<IReceipt[]>;


  @ViewChild('receiptInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger, static: false }) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
  @ViewChild('receiptInput', { static: false }) receiptInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @ViewChild('auto', { static: false }) matAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete;


  constructor(
    private _labService: LabService,
  ) { 

  _labService.onReceiptListChanged.subscribe(
    (response: IReceipt[]) => {
        this.receiptList = response;
    }
);

this.filteredReceipts = this.receiptCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  map((prm: IReceipt | null) =>
      prm ? this._filterSupplier(prm) : this.allReceipts.slice()
  )
);

  }

addReceipt(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
  if (!this.matAutocomplete.isOpen) {
      let input = event.input;
      let value: IReceipt = event.value as IReceipt;

      // Add our approver
      if (value) {
          this.receipt.push(value);
      }

      // Reset the input value
      if (input) {
          input.value = '';
      }

      this.receiptCtrl.setValue(null);
  }
}

removeReceipt(receipt: IReceipt): void {
  const index = this.receiptList.indexOf(receipt);

  if (index >= 0) {
      this.receiptList.splice(index, 1);
  }
}


private _filterSupplier(value: IReceipt): IReceipt[] {
  let filterValue = value;
  if (isString(filterValue)) {
      let filterValue = (value as any).toLocaleLowerCase('tr');
      return this.allReceipts.filter((prm: IReceipt) => {
          return (prm.StockShortName as any).toLocaleLowerCase('tr').indexOf(filterValue) >= 0
      });
  }
  else {
      return this.allReceipts.filter((prm: IReceipt) => {
          return prm.StockIntegrationCode === prm.StockIntegrationCode;
      });
  }
}


receiptSelected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
  let sUser: IReceipt = event.option.value;

  if (this.receiptList.filter((f: IReceipt) => f.StockIntegrationCode == sUser.StockIntegrationCode).length == 0) {
      this.receiptList.push(sUser);
  }

  this.receiptInput.nativeElement.value = '';
  this.receiptCtrl.setValue(null);

}
```

[image]

Comment: The mat-autocomplete is displayed as a drop-down. The mat-chip-list displays the selected items, but not in a drop-down, so I would expect the result you show in your screenshot presuming they are the selected items. I'm not quite sure what you are expecting.

Comment: Can you provide your .ts file? Your HTML seem to be following the format from https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chips-autocomplete so the issue might not be the HTML only

Comment: @Jojofoulk I added the TS code as well